# Disable cache for block Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, block-cache, product-prices

I want to disable cache for block Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price.
I know that if it was a different block I can disable it with this:

```
<action method="setCacheLifetime">
        <s>null</s>
    </action>
```

But I can't do it on Product Price, I tried with this code on `/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Product/Price.php`

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->addData(
            array('cache_lifetime'    => false)
        );
        $this->setCacheLifetime(false);
        parent::__construct();

    }
```

But it does not work, it works on my local but not on the live server and I do not know why.

Basically what i want to do is show a different price based on the visitor referal and with block cache enabled i can't.

Someone knows what can I do?

Comment: are you using any extra cache in your site?

Comment: i'm using FPC (full page cache), however if FPC is enabled and block cache is disabled it works, but if block cache is enabled it will show always the same price

Comment: which fpc you are using?

Comment: I'm using Lesti FPC

Comment: You need to find your block name of price and need to add in "Dynamic Blocks" in admin configuration of Lesti FPC

Comment: configuration settings in System -> Config -> System -> Lesti FPC.

Comment: what is the correct block name for Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price?
I already tried catalog_product_price and does not work.

Comment: And other strange thing that makes me think that the problem is not FPC is that if i disable block cache it will work